# Bluetooth Low energy random address generation

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

How the LE random address is generated, What is the algorithm it use generally to generate the same ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a random number. So not supposed to be reversable except for special cases. The upper 2 bits in the address tells if the rest is resolvable by a key. The key was exchanged between server and client when the association was made.
After that you cannot resolve it without the key.
The algorithm is in the ble specification at BTSIG.

Answer (score 1):

**random address** :: Can be of following type and sub type

```
      **Static address**  :: 2 bits of MSB should be 1,1.Other 46 bits should be randomly generated     (except all 0 or 1). 
      **Private address** :: Has following types
              **Non resolvable private address ** :: 2 bits of MSB should be 0,0.Other 46 bits should be randomly generated (except all 0 or 1), also should not conflict with public and static address.
              **resolvable private address** :: its mostly used random address and all bondable devices should use it (if privacy is required) following is the procedure
```

**Prerequisite for Non resolvable private address** ::

IRK(Identity root/resolving key) :: This key should be available to host, a 24 bit hash value will be generated using this key **hash = ah(IRK, prand)** , for **ah** function see the specifications

prand :: its a 24 bit random address having 2 bits of MSB as 1,0. also remaining 22 bits should not be all 0 or 1.

finally random address is a concatenation of Hash value and prand

**randomAddress = hash || prand**